# Multi region mask OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mask, mat

I would like to create a mask in OpenCV containing some full rectangular regions (say 1 to 10 regions). Think of it as a mask showing the location of features of interest on an image. I know the pixel coordinates of the corners of each region.

Right now, I am first initializing a Mat to 0, then I am looping through each element. Using "if" logic, I put each pixel to 255 if they belong to the region, such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i<mymask.cols, i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j<mymask.rows, j++) {
      if ( ((i > x_lowbound1) && (i < x_highbound1) &&  
         (j > y_lowbound1) && (j < y_highbound1)) || 
         ((i > x_lowbound2) && (i < x_highbound2) &&  
         (j > y_lowbound2) && (j < y_highbound2))) {
         mymask.at<uchar>(i,j) = 255;
      }
   }
}
```

But this is very clumsy and I think inefficient. In this case, I "fill" 2 rectangular region with 255. But there is no viable way to change the number of region I fill, beside using a switch-case and repeating the code n times.

Is there anyone thinking of something more intelligent? I would rather not use a 3rd party stuff (beside OpenCV ;)  ) and I am using VisualStudio 2012.

Comment: `mymask.at<i*mymask.rows + j> = 255;`  - shouldn't that be `mymask.at<some_type>(j,i) = 255;` ?

Comment: Yeah possible when I wrote the question I had no access to my code so I wrote what I remembered...

Comment: Well by "yeah possible" I mean you are totally right ;) Thanks I will correct it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cv::rectangle()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=rectangle#void%20rectangle(Mat&%20img,%20Rect%20rec,%20const%20Scalar&%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20int%20shift)):

```
//bounds are inclusive in this code!
cv::Rect region(x_lowbound1, y_lowbound1,
                x_highbound1 - x_lowbound1 + 1, y_highbound1 - y_lowbound1 + 1)
cv::rectangle(mymask, region, cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea on how to easily adapt the code in order to iterate through multiple sub region?

Comment: How do you have the regions stored currently? It might make sense to just store each one as a Rect. Then you can have them all in a vector (or some other container) and just iterate through it, calling `cv::rectangle()` for each

Comment: Ok I'll do that. My concern is that I don't know beforehand how many rectangles there will be (it is a user input, as well as the coordinates and dimensions of the rectangle), but I will iterate in a vector and it will surely be fine. Thanks!